# How to force webdriver to install app before launching it

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, appium

I recently bumped on a problem regarding installing / updating app on the device before running tests.

```
driver.init(desired)
```

It seems that when you initialize a new session, if the app is not installed, it will install it. However when an older version of the app is already installed, it won't update it.

```
it('initialise appium session', function(){
    return actionsManager.startSession(desired);
});

it('installs app', function(){
    return actionsManager.installApp(context.desired.app);
});
```

I've tried the above code but it launches the app first, and then it doesn't seem to install the app (I can see logs on appium side and it replies immediately a status 200).

Ideally the test would first clean current app, install new one and finally launch it. Could someone give me a clue on how to do that ? Thanks !

ps: I'm using mocha as a test runner, and javascript bindings on the webdriver side. Appium server is running on a mac and I'm launching the script from a PC.

Comment: Try using capability fullReset. Set it to true.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this led me to discover that actually appium server had been launched with a --no-reset argument a couple months ago.
Looks like it ends up being a problem between chair and keyboard here :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that appium server had been launched with "--no-reset" argument.

Appium's default behavior is to update the app at each new session. The "--no-reset" flag was preventing it to do so. I originally used it on my dev machine so that I could reduce the waiting time for each test.

So in the end there is nothing specific to do in the code, it's just a matter of appium server configuration.

Note: it appears that this flag will be deprecated on appium 1.5, [see documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/1.5/?ruby#appium-server-arguments).
It will still be possible to setup this behavior by using a new "–default-capabilities" flag.